# how to i execute this query line by line and then send the result to frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, es6-promise

```
const con = require("../../database/connection").getConObject();
let member = [];

function getStudent(id, callback) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const getGroupDetails =
      "SELECT g.id,s.username,s.name FROM group_list as g LEFT JOIN student_registration as s on s.id = g.id WHERE g.groupID = ?";
    con.query(getGroupDetails, id, (err, results) => {
      results.forEach((temp) => {
        member.push({ usernames: temp.username, name: temp.name });
      });

      callback(id);
      member = [];
    });
    resolve(1);
  });
}
let mergedResult = [];
function addStudent(id) {
  mergedResult.push({ id: id, members: member });
}

function getLastRecord() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const getGroupID = "SELECT groupID FROM group_list GROUP BY groupID;";
    con.query(getGroupID, (err, result) => {
      if (result && result.length > 0) {
        result.forEach((element) => {
          getStudent(element.groupID, addStudent);
        });
      }
    });
    resolve(1);
  });
}

exports.getGroupDetails = (req, res) => {
  try {
    getLastRecord().then((value) => {
      res.status(200).json({ msg: mergedResult });
      mergedResult = [];
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ msg: "Something is wrong" });
  }
};
```

I want to send the mergedresult when all the data is successfully fetched from database and the mergedresult array is not null. But some times i get null result, sometimes i get half data, sometime perfect or sometimes redundant data. Please help me fix this issue i cannot trace the promise calls. If its not possible with promise please provide me some way to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Your server has global variables `member` and `mergedResult` that are concurrently used by all incoming requests. This cannot work, one request will overwrite what a concurrent request has just written, leading to unpredictable results like you observed.

Instead of global variables, use request-local variables, for example `res.locals.member` and `res.locals.mergedResult` (see the [`res.locals` documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals)). To have access to these in your functions, pass them `res` as an additional argument, e.g.,

```js
getLastRecord(res).then((value) => {...});
```

Comment: bro can you edit the code and paste here bcz i tried myself but getting lots of errors